# How to play a seamless loop from an AudioSprite in AS3, without SAMPLE_DATA

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, mp3, howler.js

I created a batch of sounds assembled with this tool:

## AudioSprite

https://github.com/tonistiigi/audiosprite

The output is generally used for JS libraries, such as Howler, Zynga Jukebox, or SoundJS - but I wanted to see if it's possible to implement in AS3.

I started creating a Sound player that can load, parse and play the sounds based on the JSON and MP3 file this tool generates.

So far so good! ... except for loops.

Now, the **big question** is - is there a way to play a Sound-loop seamlessly given that all music & sounds coexist in the same MP3 file, and it has a **start & end** range to play and stop it?

```
Example of how the sounds are placed in the file:

mygame_sounds.mp3 = [BUZZ + LASER + BOING ... + TRACKLOOP]
```

I'm looking for a solution that **does not** involve using the `SAMPLE_DATA` Event (given it eats up a lot of CPU usage). If there's no way around it, please explain why.

So far I've had mild success using `flash.utils.Timer` objects triggered after a given AudioSprite's duration, but it's not consistent.

To stop / dispose of a *non-looping* sound, I rely on a **Master Timer** (running at very short intervals) and that seems to "cut" the sample appropriately. But I already tried using this Master Timer to play a looped-sound over and over - same latency issues.

Is there any method to predict / measure how much latency is to be expected by the time the sound completes one pass?

Comment: Sorry about the missleading [howler.js] tag, but I didn't have enough rep to create "audiosprite". If YOU can, please do. You can also substitute the tag here in this question.

Comment: Care to explain why, Mr. / Ms. Downvote?

Comment: I don't really know why the downvote so here is a +1 from me to level it up... Anyway, what kind of latency issues are you experiencing exactly? Can't you pre-process the sound file (create different Sound objects for looping sounds) in your app?

Comment: In theory, sure, a separate WAV/MP3 could be used for the sound that needs to repeat seamlessly, but this is more of a reusability concern (being able to reuse the same AudioSprite merged MP3 sounds between HTML5 and Flash, given a JSON file to describe the id/start/end/loop attributes).

Answer (score 1):

In SoundJS we could not find a way to allow smooth looping of audio sprites in AS3 and went with a timer.  We found Web Audio was the only api that allowed smooth looping, and therefore recommended staying away from audiosprites for sounds that needed to loop smoothly if any other plugin might be used.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks OJay. I've actually been messing around with the Sound's `.extract()` and `.loadPCMFromByteArray()` methods to create a separate Sound object when smooth loops are necessary. I'm not sure it works with all sound lengths, but so far I think I have something promising (will post answer later).

Comment: @bigp Yep, consider splitting that audio sprite into several elements and loop these natively, this won't make huge overhead since you can pack all the resultant MP3s into a single SWF to download, with a XML/JSON metadata to explain what file is what, if you're say using an interchangeable character voiceover set spoken on different languages.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of why you can't get smooth loops of a track retrieved from a larger audio file is that you cannot check sound position faster than once per SWF frame, which length depends on `stage.frameRate` and total processing time of your application and is generally varied. So, if your looping sounds lasts say 5.123 seconds (I don't care how many samples, just that its length does not make a full number of frames regardless of `stage.frameRate`), your sound will attempt to play for either 5.125 seconds (205 frames at 40 fps, IMO best bet for this particular sound), 5.133 seconds (154 frames at 30 fps) or some weird number of frames if the SWF would experience lag. The excess milliseconds cannot be totally controlled by any means due to AS3/Flash engine optimization. So, consider not using audio sprites and shift into audio packs (several audio files in an SWF, or one sound in an MP3).

Comment: Good points regarding the frame-rate. I've done the SWF Sound-pack thing in the past, and while it is good and reliable for Sound loops, I was just curious if it could be swapped by the AudioSprite format using only one Sound object to load and play everything. 

I was able to get smooth loops in the end (cropping just the right amount of samples to extract/loadPCM). That being said, I think it might be worth looking into a hybrid, where each "sprite" instantiates a new Sound, extracting from the main Sound file. Then, any sounds can loop even if they are not marked to in the JSON file.

Comment: Splitting your audio sprite on the AS3 end? Sure, this should do for seamless looping.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm still working on the perfect solution, this is the best I could come up with:

1. Load the JSON file / ByteArray.
2. Parse the JSON file to obtain each sprites' ID, start and end times.
3. Load the MP3 file / ByteArray (requires `loadCompressedDataFromByteArray()`) into a master Sound object.
4. Once loaded, check if any sprites are marked as "loops".
5. Create separate Sound objects for the above loops, and extract the portion from the *master* Sound via `loadPCMFromByteArray()` with some "**magic-numbers**" (details below).
6. To play a one-shot sound, call the master Sound's `play(sprite.start * 1000)` (depending on the format, usually the JSON's `start` values are in seconds, needs to be in milliseconds).
7. To play a seamless-loop sound, call the individual Sound object's (created in step #5) `play(0, 9999)` method.

I won't go too deep in details on how to stop the sounds (`SoundChannel.stop()`, bam!), but I'll explain the "magic-numbers" mentioned above. See this snippet:

```
    var goldenOffset:UInt = (64 << 5);
    var goldenDuration:UInt = (64 << 2);
    var sampleRate:UInt = 44100;
    
    for (id in loops) {
        var sprite:AudioSpriteItem = _mapSprites.get(id);
        var loop:Sound = _mapLoops.get(id);
        var sampleBytes = new ByteArray();
        var samplesTotal:UInt = cast(sprite.duration * sampleRate + goldenDuration);
        var samplesStart:UInt = cast(sprite.start * sampleRate + goldenOffset);
        
        _sound.extract(sampleBytes, samplesTotal, samplesStart);
        
        sampleBytes.position = 0;
        loop.loadPCMFromByteArray(sampleBytes, samplesTotal, "float", true);
    }
```

Quite honestly, these magic **goldenOffset** and **goldenDuration** values were just found via Trial-and-Error. I could get *close* to a seamless loop without them by just calculating the `start` and `duration` with the `sampleRate` (assuming 44100 by default), but each endings had a bit of a hiccup to it.

After several adjustments, those couple "64 left bit-shifted" values made the loops sound smoother.

I posted the Haxe project on github (compiled SWC also available in `/bin` folder) if you wish to try it / read through the code.

## FLAudioSprite

Github page: https://github.com/bigp/FLAudioSprite

SWF Demo (Download): [bit.ly/FLAudioSpriteSWFDemo](http://bit.ly/FLAudioSpriteSWFDemo)